# How convert MemoryStream to FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

is work:

```
using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(zipFile)))
{
  ZipEntry theEntry;
  while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
  {
  }
}
```

not work, memorystream

```
using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(memorystream))
{
    ZipEntry theEntry;
    while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)//Exception **EOF in header**
    {
    }
}
```

how convert ?

Comment: _What_ works? _What_ doesn't? Errors? Exceptions? What are they? You need to provide all the relevant information.

Comment: What exception do you get ? Any Stream should work.

Comment: Where are you getting `ZipInputStream` from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without knowing more about the `ZipInputStream` you're using, the only guess I can hazard is that it's trying to use the `MemoryStream` you're passing it before that stream's position has been reset to the beginning. Try adding this line before your code snippet:

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: +1, since this is a really good guess based on the information provided.

Comment: That, and I ran into an extremely similar problem earlier today. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
FileStream fs = new Filestream();
```

The call to `new Filestream();` is incorrect.  `FileStream` doesn't have any constructors that take zero arguments.